# Variable assignment with blank space

Tags: python, matplotlib

I often encounter some pieces of python codes like the following:

```
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)
```

(*The line above is borrowed from a widgets example from matplotlib itself*)

I wanted to know what does the assignment `l, = ...` really mean?

Comment: `l, = something` is basically equivelant to `l = something[0]`. This is kind of a special case of *sequence unpacking* since the number of variables and number of elements in the sequence you're trying to assign are both 1. Compare with something like `l, m = [1, 2]`. I'm not a fan of this kind of syntax though since it doesn't make it clear that `plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)` is actually returning a tuple. This is also equally valid `[l] = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)`.

Comment: @eugenhu please don't post answers in comments. Also: you are wrong: `plt.plot` returns a list, not a tuple, and `l, = foo()` is not equivalent to `l = foo()[0]`

Comment: @FlyingTeller I didn't feel like it was a complete answer (and I didn't really want to write one) but it gives enough of an explanation to be helpful. And yeah they're not the same, I didn't phrase that well but what I was trying to show was in this scenario they will achieve the same things. `l, = something` will fail if `something` is a sequence of more than one element. Also you're right that `plt.plot` returns a list, that's my mistake when I typed that, but my point was just I don't like this kind of `l, = ...` usage.